# vue-loader server-side script in a custom block

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-loader

I use webpack2 with vue-loader to bundle my web application and I would like to add some server-side script in my `.vue` files.

I would like this server-side script to be bundled into a separate file(s) that stay on the server and could be `require()`d by nodejs. This server-side script may include server-side API for the component.

I saw that I could create [Custom Blocks](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/configurations/custom-blocks.html) inside `.vue` files (eg. `<server-script></server-script>`) but I am unable to setup this.

For example, I have a `weather.vue` component that already contains everything to display the weather of the day and I want to add a custom block in this file that will contain the server API for the component.

```
<template>
  <div class="weather">...</div>
<template>

<style type="text/css">...</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
  module.exports = {
    ...
    $http.get('/api/weather')
    .then( /* update the view */ );
    ...
  }
</script>

<server-script>
  request('myRouter').addRoute('/api/weather', function(req, res) {
    res.send( /* the weather data */ );
  }
</server-script>
```

I tried to use the `extract-text-webpack-plugin` as vue-loader `options.loaders` but it ends up with a file that does not contain the expected data.

I am quite new with webpack and I don't know how to continue.

Comment: what do you mean by *"server-side script"*? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @EliranMalka: I added more details in the question

Comment: i still don't quite follow - can you elaborate on the intent? what is the goal of these scripts?
anyhow the scripts will be included in the client-side code, so how do you expect them to run on the server? or you just want server side rendering of these custom blocks?

Comment: @EliranMalka: I added an example

Comment: could you provide a sample (pseudo-) code for the intended result? i.e. a `*.vue` file with your desired code already inside.

Comment: Still not seeing a proper example. We can not really help you like this.

Comment: I added a pseudo-code example